# visual foxpro database connection issues

Tags: c#, connection-string, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am putting together an application that connects to a vfp database.  I have it working fine if I define my connection string in the app.config file -

```
<add name="vFoxProSource" connectionString="Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=C:\directory\database.dbc;Collating Sequence=machine;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

Ultimately, the path to the source will be dynamic, so I am trying to define the connection string using ConnectionStringSettings.  I have the following code -

```
ConnectionStringSettings vfpConnectionStringSettings = new ConnectionStringSettings();
vfpConnectionStringSettings.ProviderName = "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
vfpConnectionStringSettings.ConnectionString = ".. my connection string...";
```

When I run this code, I am getting the following error -

```
The 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

I have even tried pulling the provider name directly from the connection string that is working successfully, but I get the same error.  Does anyone have any idea why it is working one way, but not the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here turned out to be a problem with the connection string, not the ProviderName.  Since it was erroring out on the ProviderName, I incorrectly assumed that it was a problem there, but there was a piece missing from the connection string.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

One site that might help you in the future is http://connectionstrings.com/